# Class evaluation takes too long. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, navigation

I'm playing with sticky navigation. The problem is that evaluation/application of `fixed`/`static` class pairs takes too long.

the markup looks like this:

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="navController">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content(@"~/assets/img/logotype.png")" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <ul ng-class="{fixed: useFixedPosition, static: !useFixedPosition}">
        <li><a href="#" class="home">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#header ul.fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; }
#header ul.static { position: static; }
```

the controller code looks like this:

```
app.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
    $scope.useFixedPosition = false;
    $document.on('scroll', function() {
        $scope.useFixedPosition = $document.scrollTop() > 385;
    });
}]);
```

I'm using `angular-scroll` plugin (https://github.com/durated/angular-scroll)

What am I doing wrong?

**edit**

Thanks to @Plantface there's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud7k2po1/11.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I would love to but I don't know how do I reference the plugin in jsfiddle. I didn't find it at jsdelivr? Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly does "slow" mean? What is the actual symptom you're experiencing? Is it that the class itself is applied slowly, or is it that the effect triggered by it is slow? They're two different things.

Comment: The condition (`$scope.useFixedPosition = $document.scrollTop() > 385;`) evaluates rather quickly. But it takes about 4-5 seconds to apply fixed position to the given ul. It takes too long for (exactly) class to be applied.

Comment: @lexeme You can take the distribution file from github and useGitRaw to find a URL that works in jsFiddle. You can fork this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/ud7k2po1/) I made for you and try to make it work with your code.

Comment: @lexeme I fixed some errors in loading the plugin (http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/ud7k2po1/).

Comment: @Plantface here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/ud7k2po1/11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You should call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your scroll event.

Longer answer: If the digest cycle is not run then the watchers responsible for the two way binding with the DOM is not run. Since the `.on()` method is in jQuery or jQLite it seems they are not $scope aware or something.

However running dirty checking for every scroll event is not very efficient so you would be better off doing the DOM manipulation without `ng-class` in a directive like this:

```
app.directive('floatingNav', 
  function($document) {
    return {
      link : function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        var breakpoint = ($attr.floatingNav ? parseInt($attr.floatingNav) : 200);
        var isFloating = false;
        $document.on('scroll', function(){
          if(!isFloating && $document.scrollTop() >= breakpoint) {
            $element.addClass('floating');
            isFloating = true;
          } else if(isFloating && $document.scrollTop() < breakpoint) {
            $element.removeClass('floating');
            isFloating = false;
          }
        });
      }        
    }
  });
```

Replace your `.fixed` style with `.floating` (remove the `.static` since it's redundant) and use it like this:

```html
<ul floating-nav="385">…</ul>
```